# PHP валидация XML по собственному DTD

Tags: php, xml, валидация

Нужно провалидировать загружаемый на сервер XML-файл по уже имеющемуся на сервере файлу DTD.

Я пробовал воспользоваться [`DOMDocument::validate`](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.validate.php), но она не возвращает `bool`, как сказано в документации, а выдает `Exception`.  Более того, `DOMDocument::validate` обязывает к тому, что бы путь к DTD-файлу был заранее прописан в XML-файле.

Мне нужно валидировать загруженный XML-файл собственным DTD, игнорируя указанный внутри XML. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Если формирование XML находится в вашей власти (то-есть вы контролируете его содержимое) - то вы вполне можете указать ссылку на нужный вам DTD:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE rootElement SYSTEM "/путь/к/файлу/готовый.dtd">
   ```
2. Если DTD, связанный с вашим XML, совпадает с тем, что у вас сервере и этот DTD объявлен как PUBLIC, то вы можете использовать [resolveExternals](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.resolveexternals)
3. И наконец панк-вариант: загружаем документ как он есть и перед валидацией тупо меняем строку `<!DOCTYPE...>` на нужную.